# Is a transit visa required for Malaysia?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder. I'm planning to travel to China in January and have to transit in Malaysia. I wonder whether I can obtain a Malaysian transit visa in KLIA 2 when I'm flying back to Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I obtain a Malaysian transit visa in KLIA  when I'm flying back to Sri Lanka?

Actually if have you a valid visa from China and you intend to transit in Kuala Lumpur, any airport, yes you can stay up to 120 hours, provided the transit time is longer than 8 hours and travel only with Malaysian Airline or AirAsia.

Source:[Ministry Of Foreign Affairs](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information)

TRANSIT WITHOUT VISA FOR CITIZENS OF
BANGLADESH, PAKISTAN, INDIA AND SRI LANKA
(INDIAN SUB CONTINENTAL COUNTRIES)

CONDITIONS FOR APPROVAL OF TRANSIT WITHOUT VISA FACILITY

1. Transit Without Visa (TWOV) facility is not offered other than to Indian Sub Continental Countries citizens.
2. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not possess visa from 3rd country of destination as follows:

·       Australia
·       New Zealand
·       United States of America
·       Japan
·       China
·       Taiwan
·       South Korea

3. TWOV facility cannot exceed more than 120 hours (5 days).
4. TWOV facility is not available at entry point other than Kuala Lumpur International Airport (KLIA) and Low Cost Carrier Terminal (LCCT).
5. TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than Malaysia Airlines and Air Asia. At present only MAS and Air Asia have agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian Government.
6. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not fulfil the following:

· Valid national passport or internationally recognized travel document;
· Travel documents valid for more than six (6) months from the date of entry;
· A return ticket to country of origin;
· Not listed in the Immigration Department’s suspected list.

7. There will be no extension of TWOV facility.
8. Permanent resident and long term pass holder are not bound to any of the TWOV regulations and condition stipulated above.

> However your question is while can you transit on your way back?

Only possible if you have a valid visa issued by China,  Australia, Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of Sri Lanka and you meet all the above requirement then it is possible.

Comment: Any update for this?