# Applying for a Malaysian transit visa online for a Sri Lankan

Tags: visas, transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder, who is currently residing in Australia. When I'm traveling back to Sri Lanka through Malaysian airlines, I have a 16-hour transit. I would like to get a transit visa for this duration. After checking the answer from this [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/malaysian-transit-visa-for-sri-lankan), I called the Malaysian Airlines office in Australia from this [Contact](https://www.malaysiaairlines.com/au/en/help.html) page. They instructed me to apply for a transit visa online, as they do not offer transit visa on arrival anymore.

1. Where can I apply for a transit visa online?
2. What are the documents I should submit?
3. How much will it cost me? Or will it be free since I'm flying with Malaysian Airlines?

Comment: You have an Australian resident permit (or long term visa), correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking via Timatic, courtesy of the [Emirates visa check](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) indicates that you should not need a visa to transit.

A cross check on [Immigration Department of Malaysia](http://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/visa/types-of-visa.html) web portal notes:

> 3. Transit Visa
>
> This is issued to foreign nationals who require a visa to enter Malaysia on transit to other countries. Foreign nationals on transit without leaving the airport premises and who continue their journey to the next destination with the same flight do not require a transit visa.

The [KLIA2 Airport visa information](http://www.klia2.info/trips/malaysia/malaysia-visa-information)

Transit visa is not required for passengers who meet one of the following conditions:

- Arriving/departing at KLIA
- Have a valid visa issued by one of seven countries
- Flying with Malaysia Airlines or Air Asia
- Staying for less that 120 hours

Also, Sri Lankan nationals are among those eligible to Transit Without Visa (TWOV) and allows a stopover (after clearing Immigration) with:

- Onward ticket for within 120 hours.
- Arrival and departure from the same airport.
- A valid onward ticket and a Single or Multiple Entry Visa issued by and are heading to/from Australia, New Zealand, USA, Japan, China, Taiwan, South Korea
- Passport with a minimum validity of 6 months.
- Printed copy of itinerary and original tickets (PNR/booking number not accepted).

You'll find the above (edited for clarity) on the Kuala Lumpur International Airport [visa information](http://www.klia2.info/trips/malaysia/malaysia-visa-information).